# Polygon in Python: What is the format of CSV file for plotting polygon in Python

Tags: python, plot, polygon

I have two questions:

1. **How to store latitude/longitude in CSV for polygon?**
2. **How to plot the polygon data from a CSV file in Python?**

The CSV file should contain polygon info (latitude, longitude) and other info of that polygon like as polygon name, human population in that polygon, etc.

**Any example of python code for this problem?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use a JSON file in which you can store a dictionnary like : {name : "Name", population : 256, points : [[0, 1], [1, 1], [5, 3]]} when a CSV is only a 2d matrix.

Comment: @Cadeyrn Hi, thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with JSON file format. Can you give me an example of JSON file format for Polygon data?

Comment: reading a json in python is really easy ([here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/) is a tutorial) and I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/how-to-store-lines-and-polygons-in-json-documents) example to store geographical data.